# A better approximation than mine for $\int_0^1\log\left(1+\operatorname{gd}(x)\right)\,dx$, where $\operatorname{gd}(x)$ is the Gudermannian function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

Let $\operatorname{gd}(x)$ the Gudermannian function, defined as in this [MathWorld's article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Gudermannian.html), and implemented in Wolfram Language as *Gudermannian[x]*.

This afternoon I've spent an hour playing with [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com) about integrals, for instance, like this $$I=\int_0^1\log\left(1+\operatorname{gd}(x)\right)\,dx.$$
Notice that the plot in previous article of MathWorld tell us that for $0<x<1$ one has $0<\operatorname{gd}(x)<1$.

My calculations to get an approximation were $$I\approx\int_0^1 \operatorname{gd}(x)\,dx=-\frac{\pi}{2}+i\left(\operatorname{Li_2}(-ie)-\operatorname{Li_2}(ie)\right)-2C,$$ where I've combined with the indefinite integral of the Gudermannian functions that tell us MathWorld. Here $C$ is Catalan's constant. But this quantity is about $\approx 0.464065$.

But WA calculated $I$ as $0.365619$, play this code: 
`integrate log(1+(gd(x)))dx, from x=0 to x=1`

> **Question.** Can you provide us a better approximation, than mine, for our integral $$\int_0^1\log\left(1+\operatorname{gd}(x)\right)\,dx?$$
>   Please provide also the more important justifications in your calculations. Also if your approach uses the numerical analysis and/or calculations with your computer provide us some detail of your calculation/method. **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: To make it more standard, you could substitute $$u = \text{gd}(x),$$ which leads to $$\int_0^\alpha \frac{\log(1+u)}{\cos u} \, du,$$ with $\alpha = \text{gd}(1).$

Comment: Many thanks, @πr8 and thanks for your help and attention. I am an aficionado but your formulas seem very nice. Feel free to edit the post, any case.

Comment: You should be able to use the Taylor Series for $\log(1+x)$, take a few terms, and integrate termwise to get a good approximation

Comment: Seems a very good strategy, many thanks @BrevanEllefsen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gudermannian function is lower-bounded by the line going to $(0,0)$ and $(1,\operatorname{gd}(1))$. However, it doesn't make a very large difference, and it hence gives a reasonable approximation.

See, for example, a plot here on [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(Gudermannian%5B1%5D-Gudermannian%5B0%5D)x,+Gudermannian%5Bx%5D+from+x%3D0+to+x%3D1%7D).

Now note that

\begin{align*} \int_0^1\log\left(1+\operatorname{gd}(x)\right)\,dx &> \int_0^1\log\left(1+\operatorname{gd}(1)x\right)\,dx \\ &= \left[ x \log(\operatorname{gd}(1) x + 1) + \frac{\log(\operatorname{gd}(1) x + 1)}{\operatorname{gd}(1)} - x\right]^1_0 \\ & =  \log(\operatorname{gd}(1)+ 1)  +\frac{\log(\operatorname{gd}(1)+ 1)}{\operatorname{gd}(1) }  - 1 \\ &\approx 0.344043 \end{align*}

---

Even more simply, one can approximate the integral by $$\frac{\log(1+\operatorname{gd}(1))+\log(1+\operatorname{gd}(0))}{2} = \frac{\log(1+\operatorname{gd}(1))}{2} \approx 0.31184$$

Comment: Many thanks, your reasonings an approximations are very good.

Comment: @user243301 Thank you for the accept, but I wouldn't accept an answer too fast on this question - there are many users on this site with far more experience with integrals than I, and they might be able to do much better, or even find an exact value for this integral.

Comment: Then I am sorry, you are right, but your answer was very good and quick. Any case many thanks. Now I've unaccepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

For sure, you could use Taylor expansion
$$\log (1+\text{gd}(x))=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^4}{12}+\frac{3 x^5}{40}-\frac{x^6}{18}+\frac{169
   x^7}{5040}-\frac{19 x^8}{840}+\frac{2171 x^9}{120960}+O\left(x^{10}\right)$$ and integrate which would lead to $$\int_0^1 \log (1+\text{gd}(x))\,dx=\frac{443161}{1209600}\approx 0.366370$$ Continuing the expansion to $O\left(x^{20}\right)$ would give $$\int_0^1 \log (1+\text{gd}(x))\,dx=\frac{35582823156912797}{97316080327065600}\approx 0.365642$$ May be, better would be to use Padé approximants; a very simple would be 
$$\log (1+\text{gd}(x))\approx \frac{x-\frac{x^2}{2}}{1-\frac{x^2}{6}}$$ and the integration would lead to  $$\int_0^1 \log (1+\text{gd}(x))\,dx\approx 3+3 \log \left(\frac{6}{5}\right)-3 \sqrt{6} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\right)\approx 0.361349$$ Using the next one
$$\log (1+\text{gd}(x))\approx \frac{-\frac{17 x^3}{60}+\frac{6 x^2}{5}+x}{\frac{2 x^2}{5}+\frac{17 x}{10}+1}$$ we can still integrate and get a bunch of logarithms for a value $\approx 0.364644$.

Just for the fun, I put in the next table the decimal value of the integral of the $[n,2]$ Padé approximant
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \text{result} \\
 2 & 0.3613491513 \\
 3 & 0.3646438085 \\
 4 & 0.3661395229 \\
 5 & 0.3657879040 \\
 6 & 0.3654692466 \\
 7 & 0.3655746142 \\
 8 & 0.3656449849 \\
 9 & 0.3656298359 \\
 10 & 0.3656072339
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Padé approximants! You know a lot of tricks. Many thanks I am going to read and study your nice answer.

Comment: @user243301. You will know many and more with age (that is the problem). Padé approximants are just beautiful and so superior to Taylor series. Have a look on this site to see many examples. Cheers and thanks for the challenging problem ! Good luck in your studies.

Answer (score 0):

You considered $\log(1+x)\approx x$ forgetting that gd(x) goes from 0 to 0.6 circa on the given interval, that is too much and gives a huge error

Compare $\log(1+0.4)\approx 0.33;\;\log(1+0.5)\approx 0.4$ and $\log(1+0.6)\approx 0.47$

This causes your approximation being too high. Taking  integration limit lower than 1, like 0.2 or 0.3 gives good approximation.

Comment: Many thanks for this detail, you are right.